# How to fix "Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable"?

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses

Here's the function:

```
   function withdrawMoney() public {
        address payable to = msg.sender;
        to.transfer(this.getBalance());
    }
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.
  --> pay.sol:16:9:
   |
16 |         address payable to = msg.sender;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

someone suggested to remove the *payable* keyword, but then I can't use *transfer* keyword on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Before Solidity version `0.8.0` it was possible to implicitly convert a type `address` to a type `address payable`.

But from Solidity version `0.8.0` and on, we need to explicitly cast an `address` type to a `address payable` like:

```js
address payable to = payable(msg.sender);
```

Answer (score 0):

explicit conversion:

`address payable to = payable(msg.sender);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function withdrawMoney(address payable to) external {
     to = msg.sender;
     to.transfer(this.getBalance());
    }
```

This is a way to do it. Casting the address as payable in the function args simplifies the whole thing for you.
You can also use a bool to ensure that the transaction returns true.